# Git - How can I clean up multiple merge commits?

Tags: git

I tried to squash a merge commit I had to do because I wasn't aware that I pushed something onto the branch from a different computer, but then I noticed, merge-commits don't appear in git-log, so I basically have this weird history now where two identical commits appear twice:

```
40fdd9 (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD) Merge branch 'master' of github./Project
bbaf22 Refactored ...
3ec9f6 Merge branch 'master' of github.com:/Project
eabb68 Refactored ...
a54681 Update README.md
```

I would like to have this structure

```
newHash (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD) Refactored ...
a54681 Update README.md
```

Can someone help me out what I have to do?

Any help is very much appreciated

Comment: Please show us your `git log` with `--graph`. It will show the connections between the commits. It will make more sense.

Comment: Do you want to eliminate both the update merges and the incidental refactoring commits?

Answer (score 1):

Merges when you update a branch, and incidental changes, are both unnecessary to understand the history of the project. They just clutter things up.

To avoid the update merges, use `rebase` instead of `merge` when updating. Instead of merging in the branch, this rewrites your commits as if they were on top of the branch all along.

Let's say you have this and you'd like to get the latest updates from master.

```
A - B - C - D [master]
     \       
      1 - 2 - 3 [feature]
```

If you merge, you wind up with a merge commit that doesn't tell you any useful information.

```
$ git merge master

A - B - C - D --- [master]
     \           \
      1 - 2 - 3 - M [feature]
```

But if you rebase, its as if you were working on the latest version of master all along. History is nice and clean.

```
$ git rebase master

A - B - C - D [master]
             \       
              1' - 2' - 3' [feature]
```

The caveat is because their parent commit has changed, the commit IDs have changed. If you already `git push`ed feature you can't just push it again. It will tell you it has "diverged". You're not adding commits on top of origin/feature.

```
(origin repo)
A - B - C - D [master]
     \       
      1 - 2 - 3 [feature]

(local repo)
A - B - C - D [master]
             \       
              1' - 2' - 3' [feature]
```

To get around this, use `git push --force-with-lease` to tell Git that no really, you want to replace the branch. ***Not `--force`***. `--force-with-lease` is safer, [this article explains why](https://blog.developer.atlassian.com/force-with-lease/).

You can do a rebase even after you've already done update merges. Once rewritten on top of an updated master, the merge commits will have no changes and Git will remove them.

---

Similarly, we can use rebase to rewrite your commits and merge them together. This time it's an "interactive rebase". `git rebase -i master` will present you with an editor of all the commits in your branch. Then you can choose to edit commits, or squash them together into a single commit.

You'll see something like...

```
pick a54681 Update README.md
pick eabb68 Refactored ...
pick bbaf22 Refactored ...

# Rebase 710f0f8..bbaf22 onto 710f0f8
#
# Commands:
# p, pick <commit> = use commit
# r, reword <commit> = use commit, but edit the commit message
# e, edit <commit> = use commit, but stop for amending
# s, squash <commit> = use commit, but meld into previous commit
# f, fixup <commit> = like "squash", but discard this commit's log message
...
```

Then change `pick` to what you want to do. In this case `fixup`.

```
pick a54681 Update README.md
fixup eabb68 Refactored ...
fixup bbaf22 Refactored ...
```

Save and quit, and Git will mash the three commits together into one.

Alternatively, you can do this on the fly by "amending" the previous commit with `git commit --amend`. Instead of making a new commit, Git will add your changes to the previous commit. This is handy for quick typo fixes and simple refactorings of the previous commit.

See [Rewriting History](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History) in Pro Git for more.